# Mobile First Server Configuration Tool log removal

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

MobileFirst Server 6.3
DB2 10.x
Lunux 6.5

Installed MFP Configuration tool, and created a configuration instance.  Next, I created and deployed a runtime configuration for my application.  I see there are associated logs relating to these activities.

Next I undeloyed the runtime from the applications server, and then deleted the runtime from the GUI.  I read and understand that the runtime definition although no longer is shown in the GUI, it's definition still exists in the DB.

Is there a way to delete the logs from the GUI and/or server that related to the deploy, and undeploy of the runtime?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the log files. They are stored there only for your convenience.

These log files are in the Server Configuration Tool's data directory.

The location of this directory can be determined through **File > Preferences > IBM Worklight Server Configuration Tool > Directory for configuration files**. The default location is:

- On Unix: `$HOME/.worklight/server-configuration-tool/`
- On Windows: `C:\Users\user-name\Documents\IBM Worklight Server Data\Server Configuration Tool\`

Inside this directory:

- For 6.0 and 6.1 configurations, the log file name is `logs/config-name/operation_timestamp_outcome.log`.
- For 6.2 and 6.3 configurations, the log files for an operation form a directory `Configuration_config-name/logfiles/operation_timestamp/`.

Additionally, in version 6.2 or newer, there are log files in this directory:

- On Unix: `$HOME/.worklight/configuration-logs/`
- On Windows: `C:\Users\user-name\Documents\IBM Worklight Server Data\Configuration Logs\`